# Usage of 'couple'

Tags: subcontinental-english

When to use 'of' with 'a couple' and when not to?
Like we say 'I ate *a couple of bananas* today' and 'Give me *a couple more minutes*'. So is there any specific rule which we have to keep in mind? 
Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

It's ok to say *a couple of minutes* or *a couple more bananas* also.

Comment: Thank you Sam! I was just using the example of bananas and minutes. I wanted to know if there is any clear-cut rule as to when to use only *a couple* and when to use *a couple of*